# How to get first and last records grouping by a certain column?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, _id INT, name VARCHAR(30), age INT);
INSERT INTO test
(id,  _id,     name,       age) VALUES
(1,     1,  'Lorem',        20),
(2,     1,  'Ipsum',        21),
(3,     1,  'Dolor',        22),
(4,     1,  'Sit',          23),
(5,     1,  'Amet',         24),
(6,     1,  'Consectetur',  25),
(7,     1,  'Adipiscing',   26),
(8,     2,  'Elit',         27),
(9,     2,  'In',           28),
(10,    2,  'Non',          29),
(11,    2,  'Gravida',      30),
(12,    2,  'Erat',         31),
(13,    2,  'Tempor',       32),
(14,    2,  'Augue',        33);
```

I need a query to get the first and last records based on the `_id`. So the end result could be either this:

```
| id | _id |    name     | age |
| 1  | 1   | Lorem       | 20  | 
| 7  | 1   | Adipiscing  | 26  |
| 8  | 2   | Elit        | 27  |
| 14 | 2   | Augue       | 33  |
```

or this:

```
| min_id | max_id | _id | first_name | last_name | first_age | last_age |
|    1   |    7   |  1  | Lorem      | Adipiscing|    20     |    26    |
|    8   |   14   |  2  | Elit       | Augue     |    27     |    33    |
```

So far I tried using `group by` and `MAX` and `MIN` functions to get the `id`, but I have no idea how to get the `name` and the `age`.

Comment: Before this question had an answer I posted it in stackoverflow's chat and someone pointed out the following: "The general solution to the problem you have is the "groupwise max" problem - googling that should turn up some options". That could be useful to people who wants to learn more about this sort of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t2.id AS min_id, t3.id AS max_id, t1._id,
       t2.name AS first_name, t3.name AS last_name,
       t2.age AS first_age, t3.age AS last_age
FROM (
   SELECT _id, MIN(age) AS minAge, MAX(age) AS maxAge
   FROM test 
   GROUP BY _id ) AS t1
INNER JOIN test AS t2 ON t2.age = t1.minAge 
INNER JOIN test As t3 ON t3.age = t1.maxAge
```

This will give you the second result set. It assumes that there is *only one* min or max record per `_id`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cb1/10)

To get the first result set, you can use:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
   SELECT _id, MIN(age) AS minAge, MAX(age) AS maxAge
   FROM test 
   GROUP BY _id ) AS t1
INNER JOIN test AS t2 
   ON t2._id = t1._id AND (t2.age = t1.minAge OR t2.age = t1.maxAge)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cb1/12)

To handle the case of having multiple min, max records per `_id`, you can use:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN age = minAge THEN id END) AS min_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN age = maxAge THEN id END) AS max_id,
       _id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN age = minAge THEN name END) AS first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN age = maxAge THEN name END) AS last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN age = minAge THEN age END) AS first_age,
       MAX(CASE WHEN age = maxAge THEN age END) AS last_age
FROM (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.id) AS id, t1._id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name) AS name, t1.age, 
       (SELECT MIN(age) 
        FROM test AS t2
        WHERE t2._id = t1._id) AS minAge, 
       (SELECT MAX(age) 
        FROM test AS t2
        WHERE t2._id = t1._id) AS maxAge        
FROM test AS t1
GROUP BY _id, age ) AS t3
GROUP BY _id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e371d/5)

Comment: Thanks! I'll use an adapted version of your awnser to use the id instead of the age to join the tables, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71cb1/14

Comment: @PedroPinheiro This will work provided that the order of `id` is the same as the order of `age`. Also, in case of multiple min or max `age` values per `_id` it will pick just one value leaving the rest of the values out.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the first result:

```sql
SELECT id, _id, name, age FROM test
WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test GROUP BY _id)
   OR id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test GROUP BY _id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select minid, maxid, t.id, 
case when t._id = minid then name end as first_name,   
case when t._id = maxid then name end as last_name, 
case when t._id = minid then age end as first_age,   
case when t._id = maxid then age end as last_age
from
(
select min(_id) as minid, max(_id) as maxid, id
from tablename
group by id 
) x
join tablename t on t.id = x.id and t._id = x.minid and t._id = x.maxid
```